# Sequential animations not working with jQuery promises

Tags: jquery, animation, promise, deferred

I am trying to run 3 animations, one after the other such that only when the first one has completed does the second start and only after the second has completed the third starts.

I can do this using nested jQuery animation callbacks

```
    go("one", function () {
        go("two", function () {
            go("three", null);
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenc/m0en7avd/2/

However, I want to be able to do this using jQuery promises/deferred. I've been creating a deferred object and returning its promise. The animation callback now sets the promise to resolved and only at this point was I expecting the "then" to start:

```
go("one").then(go("two")).then(go("three"));
```

What happens though is that all animations set off at the same time.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenc/wsqm6yo1/11/

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the functions instead of calling them, your code is like the following with callbacks:

```
go("one", go("two", go("three")))
```

Instead, chain the functions:

```
go("one").then(function(){ return go("two"); }).
          then(function(){ return go("three"); });
```

As you can [see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7bp6o9u/).

Or use `bind` which returns a function with fixated arguments:

```
go("one").then(go.bind($, "two")).then(go.bind($, "three"));
```

As you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/h2z24g95/). Note that you also have [the deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) in your code - your go function can be simplified to:

```
function go(id, c) {
    return $("#" + id).animate({
        left: "300px"
    }).promise()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, great reply!